# How to dynamically add buttons to TCategoryPanelGroup?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-2009, components

Has anybody experience with Delphi 2009's TCategoryPanelGroup component and specifically with dynamically adding buttons to category panels?

I can't get it to work properly. Either the buttons do not appear or the alignment is screwed up. Basic outline of what I want to do:

```
procedure AddButton (const Caption, Group : String);
const 
  ButtonSize = 55;
  Border = 10;
var
  CategoryPanel : TCategoryPanel;
  Button : TButton;       
begin
  CategoryPanel := FindCategoryPanel (CategoryPanelGroup, Group);
  CategoryPanel.Height := CategoryPanel.Height + ButtonSize + Border;
  Button := TButton.Create (CategoryPanel);
  Button.Parent := CategoryPanel;
  Button.Width := ButtonSize;
  Button.Height := ButtonSize;
  Button.Left := 27;
  Button.Top := CategoryPanel.ClientHeight - Border - ButtonSize;
end;
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the way I specified the top coordinates.

I changed it to something like

```
ButtonCount := CategoryPanel.ComponentCount - 2;
Button.Top := Border + ButtonCount * (ButtonSize + Border);
CategoryPanel.ClientHeight := Border + (ButtonCount+1) * (ButtonSize + Border);
```

and it works.

Don't know exactly what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the problem? The buttons are shown exactly at the position required.

Are you sure you want square buttons without text?

Using :

```
Button.Left := 0;
Button.Width := CategoryPanel.ClientWidth - 2;
```

Makes them the exact width as the panel minus an offset of a pixel.

Using:

Button.Width := CategoryPanel.ClientWidth;
  Button.Left := -1;

Creates the biggest width. It There is a 1 pixel offset.

[[I'm using 2010 to be fair]].

Comment: And there is also a 1 pixel offset in the height.

Comment: In the actual application the buttons are subclasses of TButton and they contain images.

Comment: For the exact problem: the buttons do not appear at the correct location. They either do not appear at all or they are on top of each other with only a small offset.

Comment: Ok, I tried with normal TButton on 2010 and it looks ok (with regard of the 1 pixel offset). Can you dynamically create the button on a normal TPanel?

Comment: Can't try it now (no access to Delphi)...I will update on monday. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, got it to work...not sure about the reason why the above did not work for me.